# python pexpect type string code i terminal app

Tags: python, python-3.x, pexpect

I am tring to use a terminal application from python,
after run app, this app ask to imput same words.

this is my curent code :

```
import pexpect
import sys

child = pexpect.spawn("./helium-wallet create basic --seed mobile")
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer
child.expect("Space separated seed words: ")
child.sendline("carpet again stick economy finish recipe blouse forward program stumble need ginger")
# don't warry about my seed, is just a example.

print(child.before)
```

After send words, app return this error :

```
(base) admin@192-168-0-181 helium-wallet-v1.6.10-x86-64-macos % python prova.py                           
Space separated seed words: b''
```

Look like python send a byte words, and not string ...
How i can send string ?

Answer (score 0):

You never moved the pexpect cursor forward. `sys.stdout.buffer` echoed the prompt, so that is what `before` displayed. Comment out `child.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer`, and you will just get `b''`.

To move the buffer forward, you have two options:

> **NOTE** - Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 using Python 3.8

**1.** If you do not have to enter any more data, use `child.read()` to let the program run; the cursor will automatically move forward. Once `read` encounters an `EOF` (program termination), `logfile_read` will display all the output to STDOUT:

**Parent (parent.py):**

```
import pexpect
import sys

# helium-wallet.py is just a quick script I wrote to mimic your script
print("Parent: Running the child.")
child = pexpect.spawn("python3 helium-wallet.py")
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer
child.expect("Space separated seed words: ")
child.sendline("carpet again stick economy finish recipe blouse forward program stumble need ginger")
child.read()
print("Parent: Script complete. Have a nice day.")
```

**Child (helium-wallet.py):**

```
text = input("Child: Space separated seed words: ")
print("Child: Did something with:", text)
print("Child: Script complete. Have a nice day.")
```

**Output:**

```
Parent: Running the child.
Child: Space separated seed words: carpet again stick economy finish recipe blouse forward program stumble need ginger
Child: Did something with: carpet again stick economy finish recipe blouse forward program stumble need ginger
Child: Script complete. Have a nice day.
Parent: Script complete. Have a nice day.
```

**2.** If you have more data to enter (i.e., you need the child to stay alive), use `child.expect()` (I removed the `logfile` echo; using it with `before` clutters the output):

**Parent (parent.py):**

```
import pexpect

# helium-wallet.py is just a quick script I wrote to mimic your script
print("Parent: Running the child.")
child = pexpect.spawn("python3 helium-wallet.py")
child.expect("Space separated seed words: ")
child.sendline("carpet again stick economy finish recipe blouse forward program stumble need ginger")
child.expect("Requesting more data: ")

# Now you can use before to see the results of the first input,
# since you moved the cursor forward with pexpect.expect.
print()
print("First input results:")
print("Before:", child.before)
print("Match:", child.match)
print("After:", child.after)
print()

child.sendline("Here's more data!")
output = child.read()
print("Remaining output (including your input):\n", output.decode())

print("Parent: Script complete. Have a nice day.")
```

**Child (helium-wallet.py):**

```
text = input("Child: Space separated seed words: ")
print("Child: Did something with:", text)
text2 = input("Child: Requesting more data: ")
print("Child: Did something else with:", text2)
print("Child: Script complete. Have a nice day.")
```

**Output:**

```
Parent: Running the child.

First input results:
Before: b'carpet again stick economy finish recipe blouse forward program stumble need ginger\r\nChild: Did something with: carpet again stick economy finish recipe blouse forward program stumble need ginger\r\nChild: '
Match: <re.Match object; span=(204, 226), match=b'Requesting more data: '>
After: b'Requesting more data: '

Remaining output (including your input):
 Here's more data!
Child: Did something else with: Here's more data!
Child: Script complete. Have a nice day.

Parent: Script complete. Have a nice day.
```

BTW, to avoid output clutter, I would use either the one-time `child.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer`, or `print(child.before)` after each `expect`, but not both. In your case, I suggest using `child.before` to capture output only.

Good luck coding!